# swift enable to use copy() or unshare method()

Tags: ios, swift, copy

In my first Swift project, i try to make a copy of an array and his references of customs objects. After several researches, I realized that the best way is to use copy() or unshare().
But in my case, this methods doesn't exist !

For example, i declare the variable data :

```
var datas:Array<ChartColor> = [ChartColor]();
```

*(ChartColor is custom class extending NSObject)*

But if i try to copy datas into a other array, like this :

```
var datasCopied:Array<ChartColor> = self.datas.copy();
```

The copy() methods doesn't exist and Compiler Error appear :

*'Array' does not have a member named 'copy'*

My xCode Version is 6.2 (6C131e)

How to do a copy in my case ?

Comment: http://blog.human-friendly.com/swift-arrays-beta-3-hooray "*The copy() and unshare() functions are gone* because unshare has essentially become the default behaviour "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up array definition in Swift (Cmd-click) you will see that arrays in swift are essentially `struct`'s, and:

> [Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82)
>
> A value type is a type whose value is copied when it is assigned to a variable or constant, or when it is passed to a function.

... therefore, for you to copy an array a simple assignment is enough.

E.g.:

```
var source = [1, 2, 3]
var destination = source    // Copy

source[0] = 10

source                      // [10, 2, 3]
destination                 // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me !
The issue was not to copy but from a error in other method in my project who changes properties of the custom object 'ChartColor' and make then disappear in my collection view. I was disturbed by the lack of copy and unshare method !